# Window does not get focus when opened by clicking a tray icon or a launcher icon

Tags: 11.10, launcher, unity-2d, focus

When I open a window by clicking an icon in the launcher bar or an icon in the tray area, sometimes the window does not get focus and gets opened behind the currently active window. I want it to open in front of all other windows and get focus. I think that should be the correct behaviour.

This does not happen always and with all apps, but one example where this happens consistently is activating transmission from the tray icon menu - it always opens behind the current window.

I'm using 11.10 with Unity2D.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a known bug in transmission: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/transmission/+bug/741582 . Guess we have to wait until they fix it.